# Unable to use django-cachalot with django-tenants

Tags: django, caching, redis, django-cache

Trying to use [django-cachalot](https://github.com/noripyt/django-cachalot) with [django-tenants](https://github.com/django-tenants/django-tenants). I get the following error right at the start. Anyone got a resolution?

```
(cachalot.W003) Database engine 'django_tenants.postgresql_backend' is not supported by django-cachalot.
    HINT: Switch to a supported database engine.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a solution — you have to patch `django-cachalot` to generate a unique cache key for each tenant. See this open Pull Request - https://github.com/noripyt/django-cachalot/pull/123